# CSV module in python - issue with newline

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, module

I have a csv file with data as:

```
"field1"|"field2"|"field3"
"12ed"|"ksdk"|"sjdhs"
"1323"|"jdjsk
sjfsk"|"sk"k"sd"
```

My expected output

```
field1|field2|field3
12ed|ksdk|sjdhs
1323|jsjsk sjfsk|sk"k"sd
```

My two issues are in line 3. Where the data contains double quotes in double quoted csv file which it should return in the final output. And the new line/line break in the value of a column. All found in line 3.

Since I read the data as "QUOTE_NONE", I'm able to return [1:-1] data but not able to replace new line with empty value.

```
with open(fileIn, "rb") as input:
    with open(fileOut,'wb') as output:
        w = csv.writer(output, delimiter='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,quotechar='')
        for record in csv.reader(input, delimiter='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE):
            #r = map(lambda x: x.replace("\n",""), record) --> This is not working
            print([s[1:-1] for s in record])
            w.writerow([s[1:-1] for s in record])
```

Using this code, I'm able to handle quotes (first & last) and keep quotes in data. But I'm not able to handle newline.

Updated -

The csv file contents :-

```
"id"|"comments"|"Date"
"B-7"|"Hi How . 


Are You."|"2017-03-15 13:53:23.727"
"8-C"|"How was "your day" today"|"2017-02-06 11:45:26.783"
```

The Error :-

```
['"id"', '"comments"', '"Date"']
['"B-7"', '"Hi How . ']
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "try.py", line 23, in <module>
appendRecords(record, oldRecord)
File "try.py", line 8, in appendRecords
oldRecord[-1] = oldRecord[-1] + ' ' + record[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

FYI - Im using version 2.6.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add a check that if the last column of a row does not end with `"` then don't write it to the output file instead merge the next row to it and then write it to the output file.

Merge is a `list.extend` except that the last element of first list and first element of last list also get concatenated.

This code should work for you:

```
def appendRecords(record, oldRecord):
    # Check to guard against empty lines in the input csv file
    if len(record):
        oldRecord[-1] = oldRecord[-1] + ' ' + record[0]
        record.pop(0)
        oldRecord.extend(record)



with open(fileIn, "rb") as input:
    with open(fileOut,'wb') as output:
        w = csv.writer(output, delimiter='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,quotechar='')
        oldRecord = None
        for record in csv.reader(input, delimiter='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE):
            if oldRecord is not None:
                appendRecords(record, oldRecord)
                record = oldRecord

            if record[-1].endswith('"'):
                print([s[1:-1] for s in record])
                w.writerow([s[1:-1] for s in record])
                oldRecord = None
            else:
                oldRecord = record
```

Comment: oldRecord[-1] = oldRecord[-1] + ' ' + record[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I should have mentioned, m working with 2.6, that's the only option I have.

Comment: The error seems to be in accessing `oldRecord[-1]`. `def appendRecords` gets called only when `oldRecord is not None` i.e. contains the previous row data so I think it should have worked.

Comment: Can you find the rows of the input csv file where this break?

Comment: Its failing when it finds a newline/line break in the data i.e., in one of the column values.

Comment: For me, it works for the sample input you have given in the question which has linebreak in a column. Can you update the Q and add the csv lines where it is failing.

Comment: I've added the csv file contents & error in the question description

Comment: OK, so there can be multiple newlines in the column values. The `record[0]` in `def appendRecords` was breaking due to this. I have added a check for `len(record)` and it works now. See updated the answer.